# Trouble with Google API in python autosub

Tags: bash, python-2.7

I'm trying to setup autosub to translate subtitles, I checked on the Github repo and saw [this](https://github.com/agermanidis/autosub/issues/80) thread which they happen to be getting the same errors as me. However, when I tried their solution of enabling the Cloud Translation API, it didn't correct the problem. I am running this command for autosub, but I have it as a script to translate to different languages, which is why there are bash variables in the command.

```
"$tool_path" -o "$output_file" -F "$sub_format" -C 3 -K "key=$api_key" -S "$language_input" -D "$language_output" "$input_file"
```

When I run this command, I get the exact same error as in the thread, which is as follows:

```
Converting speech regions to FLAC files: 100% |################################################################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:03
Performing speech recognition: 100% |##########################################################################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:45
Exception in thread Thread-3:2% |####                                                                                                                                                                                          | ETA:  0:00:00
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 389, in _handle_results
    task = get()
  File "/home/eddy/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: ('__init__() takes at least 3 arguments (1 given)', <class 'googleapiclient.errors.HttpError'>, ())
```